# node, express, mysql update multiple rows different value arrays

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I am trying to use node/express to pass 2 separate arrays to update mysql, one array has the record id's to update and the other has the values. It is for an api endpoint to mark the sort order for folders in an app. the app will send an array of folderID's in the proper sort order i.e. `folderID = [13,10,9,12,11]` and `order = [1,2,3,4,5]`. Any help is appreciated. Here is the code I am trying but keep getting an server error:

```
const folderIDs = folderID
const folderIDSplit = folderIDs.split(',');
let folderIDArray = [];
folderIDSplit.forEach(item => folderIDArray.push(item));

let sortOrder = 0;
let sortOrderArray = [];
folderIDSplit.forEach(item => sortOrderArray.push(++sortOrder));

pool.query("UPDATE messageFolders set order = ? where id = ?", [sortOrderArray,folderIDArray ], function (error, result) {
  if (error) {
      reject(new ServerError({
        status: 500, // Or another error code.
        error: 'Server Error' // Or another error message.;
      }));
      return
    }
    resolve({
      status: 200,
      data: result
    });
  })
});
```

Comment: I think you have to change tour query to be `where id in(?)`

Comment: Can you put down the query that you wish to generate in the above example?

Comment: An IN clause wouldn't help, because mysql would accept arrays anyway. , you could loop over the array and send an UPDATE for evry combnytion of bith arrays